# Как получить произвольное число из диапазона в секции WHERE?

Tags: mysql, sql

таблица

[id] [data] [value] [min] [max]

Как записать запрос, в котором, обновление [data] пройдет если случайное число от [min] до [max] будет меньше [value]

```
UPDATE `Table` SET `data` = "some" WHERE `value` > rand(from `min` to `max`)
```

Comment: возможно вам поможет оператор `BETWEEN`.

Comment: @And нет, он никак не подойдет

Comment: возможно это дубляж вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550155/mysql-get-a-random-value-between-two-values - посмотрите там ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE `Table` SET `data` = "some" WHERE `value` > ROUND((RAND() * (`max`-`min`))+`min`);
```

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550155/mysql-get-a-random-value-between-two-values) более подробно в разрезе нескольких языков

Comment: Подскажите, это число, генерируется столько раз сколько строк проверяется или 1 раз для проверки всей таблицы?

Comment: Должно - один раз для всей таблицы. Если версия сервера БД не очень древняя...

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще 1 способ, работает, но не знаю правильно ли им пользоваться. Если кто прокомментирует буду благодарен.

```
((UNIX_TIMESTAMP() MOD (`max` - `min`)) + `min` - 1)
```

Comment: *не знаю правильно ли им пользоваться* Неправильно.

Comment: @Akina можно хоть пару причин?

Comment: Ну, например, ничто не мешает подобрать время выполнения запроса так, чтобы некая определённая запись была (или НЕ была) обновлена... а это уже ни разу не рандом.